# What does CN mean in aria2 downloading info?

Tags: downloaders

After I used aria2 to download a link, in its download link's info there is `CN:1`!

```
[#678707 16MiB/22MiB(73%) CN:1 DL:45KiB ETA:2m15s]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: After investigating, and thanks to Rinzwind, CN:1 is connection timeout in seconds.

Comment: Why is nobody posting an answer?!

Comment: @Oli cuz Mitch got me doubting myself :+)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`man aria2c`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#misc) has this way down starting on line 2480:

> ### MISC
>
> #### Console Readout
>
> While  downloading files, aria2 prints the console readout to tell the progress of the downloads. The console readout is like this:
>
> ```
> [#2089b0 400.0KiB/33.2MiB(1%) CN:1 DL:115.7KiB ETA:4m51s]
> ```
>
> This section describes what these numbers and strings mean.
>
> ```
>   #NNNNNN
>          The first 6 characters of GID in hex string. GID is an unique ID for each download.
>
>   X/Y(Z%)
>          Completed length, the total file length and its ratio. If --select-file is used, this  is  the  sum  of  selected file.
>
>   SEED   Share  ratio.  The  client  is now seeding. After BitTorrent download finished, size information is replaced with this.
>
>   CN     The number of connections the client has established.
>
>   SD     The number of seeders the client is now connecting to.
>
>   DL     Download speed (bytes per second).
> ```

So, `CN` is "The number of connections the client has established.

Comment: You can use `-x` option to set the number of connections used to download files from one server. For example, `aria2c -x 5 http://abc.abc`